# Craft SMTP emails + Localhost [Mamp pro] (+postmarkapp)

Tags: emails

Ok I'm running Mamp pro 3.0.5 for my localhost setup and php 5.3.28 and for the life of me, I can't get my localhost setup to send out emails.

My host name is **smtp.postmarkapp.com**
My **username** and **password** are my API key as specified by postmarkapp. I've tried port on both 25 and 2525, Use SMTP authentication is set to yes and SMTP Secure Transport Type is set to none.

When I run a test email through the admin panel I see **SMTP connect() failed.**

Note: emails send out correct on our dev/production servers without issue.

Anyone have ideas here?

Comment: Any warning or errors getting logged in your craft/storage/runtime/logs files?

Comment: @BradBell - yep "2014/07/30 04:16:24 [error] [application] SMTP connect() failed."

Comment: Sounds like purely a connection problem. Can you connect with those credentials on an email client or through the CLI?

Comment: telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mailer.smtp.postmarkapp.com ESMTP Postfix
EHLO Adam
250-mailer.smtp.postmarkapp.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
AUTH LOGIN
503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
421 4.4.2 mailer.smtp.postmarkapp.com Error: timeout exceeded
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: @BradBell so it looks like it's connecting but when I tried auth login it says authentication not enabled.

These same settings work correctly on our live servers. I'm only having an issue on my localhost.

Comment: Not really sure what's going on.  Maybe contact PostMark and see if they have any ideas?

Comment: You ever figure this one out, Adam?

Comment: @BradBell no. I can only assume it's config thing with my laptop as my iMac has no problem sending localhost mail. It's the same setup too! I'll probably just nuke it and start over one day.

Comment: I'm closing this because it doesn't sound like a Craft related problem.